# group by having no null values in a column

Tags: sql, oracle

If I execute the following query

```
select a, bar.c from foo
left join bar on foo.id = bar.foo
```

I get theses results

```
a   c
----------
1   1   
1   3
1   null

2   1
2   2

3   1
3   null
3   3
3   4
```

Now I would like to group theses values by `a`, but only when there is not a single null value for `b`, to only get a=2 as a result. How would I do that?

Comment: How does `bar.c` turn into `b` in your results?

Comment: black magic. (fixed, thanks)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `having`:

```
select a
from foo left join
     bar
     on foo.id = bar.foo
group by a
having count(*) = count(bar.c);
```